# Google DFP Incorrect usage of - Size mapping has to be an array

Tags: javascript, responsive, google-dfp

The DFP code I've been using on my site has been working for some time, but on fixing another issue, I noted a warning in the console for each ad slot defined:

**`Incorrect usage of googletag.Slot defineSizeMapping: Size mapping has to be an array`**

### My code

```
var mobileMapping = googletag.sizeMapping().    
                                addSize([0, 0], [320,50]).
                                addSize([0, 0], [320,100]).
                                addSize([0, 0], [320,150]).
                                build();



adSlots.ad_mobile_1 = googletag.defineSlot(   '/6129006/ad_mob_1', 
                                                          [[320, 50], [320, 100], [320, 150]], 
                                                          'ad_mob_1')                                
                                                          .defineSizeMapping(mobileMapping)
                                                          .addService(googletag.pubads())
                                                          .setCollapseEmptyDiv(true);
```

Which follows Google's own [responsive tutorial](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3423562?visit_id=1-636361328217945227-3947813573&rd=2) for how implement a sizeMapping in a defineSizeMapping call.

The warning suggested that `defineSizeMapping` expects an array, whereas `sizeMapping` seems to be outputting an object.

I've tried various implementations of the code but can't see what's wrong.... can any DFP experts shed a little light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you set the mapping for the same resolution three time in a row, try adding the ad sizes in an array :

```
var mobileMapping = googletag.sizeMapping().    
                            addSize([0, 0], [[320,50],[320,100],[320,150]]).
                            build();
```

See https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3423562?